# Avoiding Constructor Dependency Injection in trait

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have a trait and that `trait` is being used in controller. In this way, many functions of `trait` are being used in `Controller`. `Controller` is extending a Base Controller. `Controller` and `BaseController` already have their constructor.

Due to some reasons, I need constructor in trait also because I needed Constructor dependency Injection in `trait`. Now, when I place constructor in `trait`, constructor does not execute.

In order to overcome this problem, I saw `SendsPasswordResetEmails trait` at this location `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails.php`. You will see there is function called `broker` in this `trait` which returns a contract. In this way, they did not need Constructor Dependency Injection because they are getting Contract from the `broker` function

I already have a `ServiceProvider` which looks like below.

```
class RoleServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Architecture\Contract\Role\IRole', 
            '\App\Architecture\Database\Role\RoleDb'
        );
    }

    public function provides() {
        return ['App\Architecture\Contract\Role\IRole'];
    }
}
```

`App\Architecture\Contract\Role\IRole` is a Contract.
`\App\Architecture\Database\Role\RoleDb` is a Database class

**Question**: Can you kindly tell how would I connect this Service Provide through Facade like it was done in `SendsPasswordResetEmails trait` to avoid Constructor Dependency Injection in `trait` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have registered your service provider in you `config/app.php` file.

You might not necessarily need to use a `Facade` as you could just use `app()` to resolve your dependency:

```
$dependency = app('App\Architecture\Contract\Role\IRole');
```

The above will mean that `$dependency` is actually an instance of `RoleDb`.

That being said, there isn't much more to making a `Facade`.
Going off you're current structure, create the class `App\Architecture\Facades\Role`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Architecture\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Role extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'App\Architecture\Contract\Role\IRole';
    }

}
```

Then go back to your `config/app.php` file and at the bottom in the `aliases` array add the following line:

```
'Role'         => App\Architecture\Facades\Role::class,
```

And that's it.

Now, going back to the `Password::broker();` example, this is a `Facade` that has a method that actually resolves another dependancy so unless you're trying to resolve another class from within your `RoleDb` this pattern won't work for you.

You would either just use `app('App\Architecture\Contract\Role\IRole')` to resolve the dependency or use the `Facade` directly in your other controller methods.

Hope this helps!